# How to handle date localization in C# to configure Excel date format?

Tags: c#, excel, datetime, localization, cultureinfo

In c# we are using

```
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat;
```

to get the formatting for dates according to the culture settings. So on one language it might be mm/dd/yyyy and another dd/mm/yyyy.

Formatting a column in Excel works fine in English, however, when trying to format a column in excel in certain other languages it fails, because they use different letters for day, month, or year. For example, in the French Excel it is jj/mm/aaaa instead of dd/mm/yyyy. When trying to format a column using d and y, it doesn't work.

So the question is, how can I know what letter to use for d, m, and y for the different localizations?

Comment: Not that I can see. In the so the french case trying to set MM/dd/yyyy results in 03/dd/yyyy. So it recognizes the MM should be month, but it thinks the y an d are just text.